# How to represent 1D vector as sum of Gaussian curves with scipy/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gmm

**UPD: Thanks, it works.**

I have an 1D-vector, which represents a histogram. It looks like sum of few gaussian functions:
[image]

I've found `curve_fit` sample code on SO, but don't know how to modify it to receive more gaussian tuples (mu, sigma). I've heard 'curve_fit' optimizes only one function (in this case one gaussian curve).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def estimate_sigma(hist):
    bin_edges = np.arange(len(hist))
    bin_centres = bin_edges + 0.5

    # Define model function to be used to fit to the data above:
    def gauss(x, *p):
        A, mu, sigma = p
        return A*numpy.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))

    # p0 is the initial guess for the fitting coefficients (A, mu and sigma above)
    p0 = [1., 0., 1.]

    coeff, var_matrix = curve_fit(gauss, bin_centres, hist, p0=p0)

    # Get the fitted curve
    hist_fit = gauss(bin_centres, *coeff)

    plt.plot(bin_centres, hist, label='Test data')
    plt.plot(bin_centres, hist_fit, label='Fitted data')

    print 'Fitted mean = ', coeff[1]
    coeff2 =coeff[2]
    print 'Fitted standard deviation = ', coeff2

    plt.show()
```

This functions finds one gaussian curve, while visually there are 3 or 4 of them:
[image]

Please, could you advice some numpy/scipy functions to achieve gmm representation of `1D vector` in form `([m1, sigma1],[m2, sigma2],..,[mN,sigmaN])`?

Comment: You could add a second function which adds multiple ``gauss(x, *p)`` together in the right way, e.g. ``gauss(x, *p[0:2]) +  gauss(x, *p[2:4]) + ...`` and fit to that. (With an additional amplitude parameter perhaps for each term.)

Comment: @tBuLi Thanks, it works!!!

Comment: @lanery Yes, code it almost the same: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26954881/2567725. So I mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [tBuLi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1551688/tbuli) recommended, I passed additional Gaussian curves coefficients to `gauss` as well as to `curve_fit`.
Now fitted curve looks so:
[image]

Updated code:

```
def estimate_sigma(hist):
    bin_edges = np.arange(len(hist))
    bin_centres = bin_edges + 0.5

    # Define model function to be used to fit to the data above:
    def gauss(x, *gparams):
        g_count = len(gparams)/3
        def gauss_impl(x, A, mu, sigma):
            return A*numpy.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))
        res = np.zeros(len(x))
        for gi in range(g_count):
            res += gauss_impl(x, gparams[gi*3], gparams[gi*3+1], gparams[gi*3+2])
        return res

    # p0 is the initial guess for the fitting coefficients (A, mu and sigma above)
    curves_count = 4
    p0 = np.tile([1., 0., 1.], curves_count)

    coeff, var_matrix = curve_fit(gauss, bin_centres, hist, p0=p0)

    # Get the fitted curve
    hist_fit = gauss(bin_centres, *coeff)

    plt.plot(bin_centres, hist, label='Test data')
    plt.plot(bin_centres, hist_fit, label='Fitted data')

    # Finally, lets get the fitting parameters, i.e. the mean and standard deviation:
    print coeff

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Looks good! Personally I would put the definition of ``gauss_impl`` outside  that of ``gauss`` but other than that nice solution. Glad I could help :). You are allowed to answer your own questions, so you can accept this as the answer.