# Modelling a probability distribution as a fuzzy set in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, fuzzy-logic, probability-distribution

I'm trying to build a **fuzzy set** from a series of example values with `python3`.

For instance, given `[6, 7, 8, 9, 27]` I'd like to obtain a function that:

- returns `0.0` from 0 to 5ca,
- goes gradually up to `1.0` from 5ca to 6,
- stays at `1.0` from 6 to 9,
- goes gradually down to `0.0` from 9 to 10ca,
- stays at `0.0` from 10ca to 26ca,
- goes gradually up to `1.0` from 26ca to 27,
- goes gradually down to `0.0` from 27 to 28ca,
- returns `0.0` from 28ca and afterwards.

Notice that the `y` values are always in the range `[0.0, 1.0]` and if a series is missing a value, the `y` of that value is 0.0.

Please consider that in the most general case, the input values might be something like `[9, 41, 20, 13 ,11, 12, 14, 40, 4, 4, 4, 3, 34, 22]` (values can always be sorted, but notice that in this series the value `4` is repeated 3 times therefore I'd expect to have a probability of 1 and all the other values a lower probability value  -- not necessarily 1/3 as in this case).

[image: Desired result]

The top part of this picture shows the desired function plotted up to `x=16` (hand drawn). I'd be more than happy to obtain anything like it.
The bottom part of the picture shows some extra feature that would be nice to have but are not strictly mandatory:

- better smoothing than shown in my drawing (A),
- cumulative effect (B) provided that...
- the function never goes above 1 (C) and...
- the function never goes below 0 (D).

I've tried some approaches adapted from [polyfit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165259/python-numpy-scipy-curve-fitting), [bezier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643079/b%C3%A9zier-curve-fitting-with-scipy), [gauss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902283/fit-multiple-gaussians-to-the-data-in-python) or [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python), for instance, but the results weren't what I expected.
I've also tried with package [`fuzzpy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzpy) but I couldn't make it work because of its dependency to `epydoc` which seems not to be compatible with `python3`. No luck as well with [StatModels](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/stats.html#goodness-of-fit-tests-and-measures).

Can anyone suggest how to achieve the desired function? Thanks in advance.

If you wonder, I plan to use the resulting function to predict the likelihood of a given value; with respect to the fuzzy set described above, for instance, `4.0` returns 0.0, `6.5` returns 1.0 and `5.8` something like 0.85. Maybe there is another simpler way to do this?

---

This is how I usually process the input values (not sure if the part that adds the `0`s is needed), what show I have instead `???` to compute the desired `f`?

```
def prepare(values, normalize=True):
    max = 0
    table = {}
    for value in values:
        table[value] = (table[value] if value in table else 0) + 1
        if normalize and table[value] > max:
            max = table[value]

    if normalize:
        for value in table:
           table[value] /= float(max)

    for value in range(sorted(table)[-1] + 2):
        if value not in table:
            table[value] = 0

    x = sorted(table)
    y = [table[value] for value in x]
    return x, y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get x and y vectors
    x, y = prepare([9, 41, 20, 13, 11, 12, 14, 40, 4, 4, 4, 3, 34, 22], normalize=True)

    # calculate fitting function
    f = ???

    # calculate new x's and y's
    x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 50)
    y_new = f(x_new)

    # plot the results
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o', x_new, y_new)
    plt.xlim([x[0] - 1, x[-1] + 1])
    plt.show()

    print("Done.")
```

---

A practical example, just to clarify the motivations for this...
The series of values might be the number of minutes after which persons give up standing in line in front of a kiosk... With such a model, we could try to predict how likely somebody will leave the queue by knowing how long has been waiting. The value read in this way can be then defuzzyfied, for instance, in `happily waiting` [0.00, 0.33], `just waiting` (0.33, 0.66] and `about to leave` (0.66, 1.00]. In case of `about to leave` that somebody could be engaged by something (and ad?) to convince him to stay.

Comment: what does "ca" mean? and it's not clear to me what the function you're looking for should output for your [9, 41, 20, 13 ,11, 12, 14, 40, 4, 4, 4, 3, 34, 22] example. Could you clarify?

Comment: ca means circa (something close to the given value)

Comment: what should the output of the function be for [9, 41, 20, 13 ,11, 12, 14, 40, 4, 4, 4, 3, 34, 22] ?

Comment: the function of the longer example would be 0.0 from 0 to 2 or something more, then goes up to 1.0 from 2 or something more to 3, goes down to 1/3 somewhere between 3 and 4, then goes to 0.0 and stays to 0.0 till just before 9, etc. (if I could draw the resulting function easily, I would have included the picture... sorry about that).

Comment: What's the reasoning for why it's 1/3 between 3 and 4?

Comment: That's just an example: 4 is the most common value, whoose frequency is 3. All the other values in the example have frequency 1, which is 1/3 of the highest frequecy.

Comment: @RyanStout just added a hand made drawing... I hope it makes the question clearer...

Answer (score 0):

```
def pulse(x):
    return np.maximum(0, 1 - abs(x))

def fuzzy_in_unscaled(x, xs):
    return pulse(np.subtract.outer(x, xs)).sum(axis=-1)

def fuzzy_in(x, xs):
    largest = fuzzy_in_unscaled(xs, xs).max()
    return fuzzy_in_unscaled(x, xs) / largest
```

```
>>> fuzzy_in(1.5, [1, 3, 4, 5])  # single membership
0.5
>>> fuzzy_in([[1.5, 3], [3.5, 10]], [1, 3, 4, 5])  # vectorized in the first argument
array([[0.5, 1], [1, 0]])
```

This exploits the fact that the peak values must lie on the elements. This is not true for all `pulse` functions.

You'd do well to precompute `largest`, as it's O(N^2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to be sure I got it right: xs is my series of values and x is the value I want to test? What is largest? The largest x or the largest y? Can you possibly add a little main? TIA!

Comment: xs is indeed the set of values to look for membership in. This is vectorized in x, so you can test for membership of a whole array at once. Largest is the arbitrary scale factor needed to make the outcome never exceed 1

Comment: x, y = prepare([9, 41, 20, 13, 11, 12, 14, 40, 4, 4, 4, 3, 34, 22], normalize=True) returns all the x and the respective y already normalised to 1. Dividing by largest is hence needed no more? Still don't grasp how to call your function. See the updated snippet in my question...

Comment: Is there a way to make the base of the pulse larger? Thanks again!

Comment: `np.maximum(0, 1 - abs(x / 2))` would do that

Comment: brilliant, thanks!

Do you think it is possible to get the same result by combining several gauss curves by means of NoisyOR (p_1 + p_2 - p_1 * p_2)?

Comment: Only if you can define `NoisyOR` for more than two inputs. Is NoisyOR associative (`NO(NO(x, y), z) == NO(x, NO(y, z))`)?

Also, gaussian `pulse`s will break the assumption I mention in the question, so computing `largest` will be harder

Answer (score 0):

This only works (due to `np.bincount`) with a set of integers.

```
def fuzzy_interp(x, vals):
    vmn, vmx = np.amin(vals), np.amax(vals)
    v = vals - vmn + 1
    b = np.bincount(v, minlength = vmx - vmn + 2)
    b = b / np.amax(b)
    return np.interp(x - vmn - 1, np.arange(b.size), b, left = 0, right = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just tried out your solution... I think that vmin in line 3 should be replaced by vmn but anyway the result seems to be shifted right by 1...